# Google appengine multihandler

Tags: google-app-engine, httphandler

Is there a way of making a google app engine handler that handles all the urls that haven't been specified?

Maybe like:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/hello',HelloHandler),
    ('/bye',ByeHandler),
    ('for-everything-else',OtherHandler)
], debug=True)
```

Comment: Now please dont comment to tell me that 'for-everything-else' cant be a url..  'for-everything-else' is just a stub, if that is the right word

Answer (score 2):

okay i found the answer myself:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
    ('/hello',HelloHandler),
    ('/bye',ByeHandler),    
    ('/.*',OtherHandler)
], debug=True)
```